# Linux customized alias in watch command?

Tags: linux, bash

I am unable to use my customized alias command in watch utility to monitor a different queues. It says command not found, Is there any way to use aliased command in watch utility?

```
$ alias lq='ls -lhrt /home/foo/stat/*.msg'

$ watch lq
sh: lq: command not found
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no easy answer: the best I could do was to add a *function* `watchany` containing:

```
watchany() { alias "$1" 2>/dev/null| \
  ( t=`line`; if [ -n "$t" ]; then t=${t#*=\'}; t=${t%\'}; shift; \
    watch $t "$@"; else watch "$@"; fi ) }
```

It needs to be a function in order to avoid processing in a sub-shell (and the `()` brackets are for the same reason). You can add it to `.bashrc`.

I haven't pursued it to the ultimate, but as above it doesn't work properly with files or extra parameters containing embedded white spaces. If this is a problem, you will have to elaborate it yourself.

When you have satisfied yourself that it is working as you want, you can replace `watch` in the function by `$(which watch)` and then `alias watch=watchall`.

If it's only one or two aliases that you want to watch, then it is probably easiest to add extra aliases, such as:

```
alias watchlq='watch ls -lhrt /home/foo/stat/*.msg'
```

Of course you will need to remember to change `watchlq` if you ever change `lq`.

Comment: Every solution I've seen is very complicated. What I find strange is that https://github.com/antonmedv/watch can do it, but builtin watch cannot.